# How to use Unicode in "Real Name" bit of key?

Tags: unicode, gnupg

GPG appears to support Unicode, but I can't get it to actually *work*

```
% gpg --utf8-strings --display-charset utf-8 --edit-key king@example.com
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.15; Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

gpg: key xxxxxxxx: duplicated user ID detected - merged
Secret key is available.

gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
pub  4096R/xxxxxxxx  created: 2014-02-20  expires: never       usage: SC
                     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
sub  4096R/xxxxxxxx  created: 2014-02-20  expires: never       usage: E
[ultimate] (1). King George \xe2\xa3\x20<king@example.com>

gpg> uid

pub  4096R/xxxxxxxx  created: 2014-02-20  expires: never       usage: SC
                     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
sub  4096R/xxxxxxxx  created: 2014-02-20  expires: never       usage: E
[ultimate] (1). King George \xe2\xa3\x20<king@example.com>

gpg> adduid
Real name: King George Ⅳ      ### I type this.
Email address: king@example.com
Comment:
You are using the `utf-8' character set.
You selected this USER-ID:
    "King George � <king@example.com>"    ### Terminal notes corruption.

Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "King George \xe2\xa3\x20<king@example.com>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID xxxxxxxx, created 2014-02-20


pub  4096R/xxxxxxxx  created: 2014-02-20  expires: never       usage: SC
                     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
sub  4096R/xxxxxxxx  created: 2014-02-20  expires: never       usage: E
[ultimate] (1)  King George \xe2\xa3\x20<king@example.com>
[ultimate] (2). King George \xe2\xa3\x20<king@example.com>  ### That's not correct UTF-8.
```

- My terminal is set to use UTF-8.
- `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Note the bottom: The UTF-8 sequence isn't correct, but it's close! The *middle* octet of the three-byte sequence that should be there is missing. I doubt there's anything I could do to cause the middle octet to drop, so what's going on here?

Comment: Which unicode character(s) were you trying to add?  I'll test it a little ...

Comment: @Ben: It's in the question, on the line with `### I type this.`: "Ⅳ" — ROMAN NUMERAL FOUR, U+2163.

Comment: Okay, which version of the Unicode standard does your system support and does it support that full specification in all interfaces?  BTW, the answer to the second part is almost certainly no, but I'd rather not assume that.

Comment: BTW, my guess is that the interface and/or font used to interact with GPG on the command line doesn't support that character, even though other parts of the system do (the same thing occurred when I tried here).

Comment: @Ben The "interface and/or font used to interact with GPG on the command line" is the terminal; I forget whether it was iTerm2 on OS X or gnome-terminal in Linux, but both have excellent Unicode support, and both have fonts. The encoding of the input is determined by the terminal application (and is by default UTF-8 just about everywhere); this in communicated to the application via the LANG environment variable, also correctly set. I need to answer this, as this turned out to be a bug in GnuPG. (IIRC, gpg2 works just fine. gpg does not.)

Comment: Interesting, is this something Werner is aware of?  Oh, BTW, IIRC the default terminal font on OS X is Monaco.  Linux is usually one of the Courier variants, though that can change in X and it depends on which window manager.

Comment: @Ben: Who is Werner? :-) I probably need to submit a bug report if this is still present. (I need the will to dedicate my valuable free time to it.) If you mean "Courier New", I doubt it, owing to the non-free status. I was under the impression Déjà Vu Mono was the default font on GNOME; other DEs many very. You are likely correct about OS X: I've configured my laptop to use Déjà Vu. :-)

Comment: Werner Koch, the primary developer of gpg.  Although most of the current dev work is going into 2.1 (which is almost out of beta), except for security fixes, of course.

Comment: @Thanatos It's a bit old thread but answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696866/cant-import-gnupg-keys-due-to-ascii-conversion should help.